# Are numpy arrays faster than lists?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am new to using python and numpy arrays.While i was going through the notes online,saw a mention about how ndarray's are faster than lists..

> "NumPy arrays are stored at one continuous place in memory unlike
> lists, so processes can access and manipulate them very efficiently."

*So i tried using timeit on a map which sqr roots each element in the **list***

```
from timeit import timeit
timeit(stmt='import math;a_list = list(range(1,100000));list(map(math.sqrt,a_list))',number=1000)

8.955352897006378
```

*and timeit on a map which sqr roots each element in a **numpy***

```
timeit(stmt='import numpy as np;import math;np_array=np.array(range(1,100000));list(map(math.sqrt,np_array))',number=1000)

24.691162549999717
```

doesn't make sense,lists seem faster

Comment: Does `np.sqrt(np_array)` make it faster?

Comment: That doesn't really have much to do with a `numpy` array in particular; also, your `timeit` statement includes time to import the _entire_ `numpy` package, not perform an operation on a `numpy` data structure

Comment: Applying the function to the array is faster than applying the function to the list, but you also have the overhead of constructing the array and constructing a new list.

Comment: This looks like you are intentionally misusing `numpy` arrays. Timing the imports, not using `np.arange`, mapping to `math.sqrt` and converting to a list.

Comment: yeah,I realized i used `timeit` incorrectly and using `np.sqrt` does make it better.

Comment: `math.sqrt` takes a scalar input.  Iterating like this on a numpy array does not take advantage of the 'efficient' storage.  `np.sqrt` is a compiled function that does the iteration in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

introducing numpy in your code means introduce another kind of thinking at problems.

numpy in general are more expensive in the creation phase but blazing fast for vectorial computation.

I think this is more or less what you are searching for

```
timeit(stmt='list(map(math.sqrt,a_list))', setup='import math; a_list = list(range(1,100000))',number=1000)
#8.64
```

vs:

```
timeit(stmt='numpy.sqrt(a_list)', setup='import numpy; a_list = numpy.arange(100000)',number=1000)
#0.4
```

These are the results of timeit, only applied on the computation part. I mean, computing the sqrt and ignoring time to import the libraries.

Comment: thank you, i understand now.